# highlighting characters in text depending on position of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text on my website that scrolls horizontal through the page. I’m trying to get around 8 characters highlighted in black, while the rest is grey. But those characters are meant to vary as you scroll though, the highlighted bit should remain in place.

In case this doesn’t make any sense, if grey was an x, it should look something like this:

xxxxx xpsum dolox xxx xxxx
xxxx xxsum dolox sxx xxxx 
xxx xxxum dolox six xxxx x
xx xxxxm dolox sit xxxx xx

I’m trying to get this done in jQuery, but I can’t get it to work. I also like to say that I’m not at all an expert in webdesign, so I don’t know what I’m doing. Anyway, I’ve tried two different approaches, one is to say “change colour of text when going over an underlying div”. The other approach is to change the colour of the text depending on the scrolling position, but the problem here is that it takes the scrolling position of the whole div, instead of a fixed position on the page. Both don’t work at the moment, examples are here:

[jsfiddle `9p29tz2f`](http://jsfiddle.net/9p29tz2f/)
[jsfiddle `9p29tz2f/1`](http://jsfiddle.net/9p29tz2f/1/)

If anyone has any ideas how to approach this, or needs some more clarification, please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: [A quick-aid](http://jsfiddle.net/9af91wcL/), the highlight div on top and with semi-transparent color?

Comment: Good point. For some reason I didn't think that would work, but it does. The only slightly annoying thing is that it goes right over the characters, leaving them half grey-half black, whereas I prefer for the characters to change colour at ones. but I don't know if any other option would fix that. Thanks for this suggestion though!

Comment: Yes, it's a kind a negative of what you need. There are a couple of answers though, which do what you need better than my "quick-aid". If you really have to change the color character by character, this will require a whole lot more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the text and set it as a child of the overlay box then scroll them together:

```
$(function(){
    var $bodytext = $('#bodytext'),
        $clone = $bodytext.clone();         
    //copy the text and append it to #black:
    $clone.attr("id","clone").prependTo("#black");
    //scroll #clone with #bodytext:
    $bodytext.scroll(function(){
        $clone.scrollLeft($bodytext.scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9p29tz2f/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've taken Teemu's solution and modified it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/9af91wcL/2/

The important bits: The code moves a white DIV (`#grey-overlay`) on top of the text and makes it transparent. By adding black and white pixels, you get grey. The grey level is determined by the alpha channel (0.7 in the `rgba()` function).

You need to assign a height or it will look odd. I use 1.5em to make sure it doesn't overlap with the scroll bar of the `#bodytext` div.

Also make sure that the top/left position of both div's is the same.

In your real code, you can make the horizontal scrollbar disappear and scroll with JavaScript.

HTML

```
<div id="grey-overlay"></div>
<div id="bodytext">text...</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
}
#bodytext {
    top: 15%;
    width:200px;
    height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#grey-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    width:40px;
    height: 1.5em;
    top:15%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the same content within `#black` as in `#bodytext`, and synchronize its position relative to `#bodytext` scrolling. This can be achieved by using an extra wrapper around `#black`. Something like this:

CSS:

```
#cover {
    top: 15%;
    height:50%;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
#black {
    color: #000000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
}
#bodytext {
    top: 15%;
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cover">
    <div id="black"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var black = $('#black'),
        btext = $('#bodytext');
    black.text(btext.text()); // Clone the content
    btext.scroll(function () {
        var pos = btext.scrollLeft();
        black.css('left', -pos + 'px'); // Set the position to match #bodytext
    });
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koar2vmf/).

Notice, that if you need [some left margin](http://jsfiddle.net/koar2vmf/1/), it has also to be "calculated in" to `pos`.